# estimating coordinate correction

Tags: svm, k-nn, 3d-reconstruction

I'm working with 3d coordinate data (x,y,z), however I know that the z coordinate is systematically wrong and the error of z is dependant on both x and y. I however do have some data where I know the correct z value so I want to make a model that can given the xyz coordinates give  the correct z value, but I'm not sure what the best way of doing so is.

I tried using an SVM (support vector regressor) but it gives pretty bad results, I also tested k-nearest neighbor regressor and it works really well for the datapoints I have, however there are holes in the 3d space where I don't have data and I'm fairly certain the k-nearest neighbor regressor will not give correct result. I feel like there should exist a simple polynomial formula that solves the problem which is why I went for an SVM but is there any other simple method I can employ to do this correction? I feel like the problem should be solvable by a simple polynomial such as: $z_{correct} = c_0 + x*c_1 + x^2*c_2+ y*c_3 + y^2*c_4+ z*c_5 + z^2*c_6$, however I don't know what formula to use or the best way to find the constants, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitting your data to a polynomial, as you described it, is called "polynomial regression". It is equivalent to a linear regression where you introduce new features for $x^2, x^3, ...$.

There is a closed-form solution to find the optimal constants. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/closed-form-solution-to-linear-regression-e1fe14c1cbef) you can find details on the algebra to implement it. Nevertheless, it is also possible to find the values for the constants by means of gradient descent methods. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23128/40048) you can find a discussion on why using one method or the other.

The gradient descent approach can be easily implemented with any deep learning framework, like Pytorch or Tensorflow. For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920429/674487) you have an example of a Pytorch implementation.